# Weakly Compact Generated spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Weakly Compact generated is if there is weakly compact subset $K$ of Banach space $\mathbb{X}$ that closed liner span is $\mathbb{X}$.

> **Corollary 3.** *A Banach space $X$ is weakly compact generated if and only if there is a reflexive Banach space $R$ and a one-to-one operator $T:R\longrightarrow X$ with $T(R)$ dense in $X$.*
>
> *Proof.* The sufficiency is obvious. For the necessity, let $K$ be a weakly compact subset of $X$ whose linear span is norm dense in $X$ and in Lemma $1$ let $W$ be the convex hull of $K\cup (-K)$, so that $Y$ is reflexive and $j$ gives the desired one-to-one operator.    $\square$

This is from [Creating a reflexive Banach space from a weakly compact set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113380/creating-a-reflexive-banach-space-from-a-weakly-compact-set/117519#117519) (Philips answer)

I have trouble with sufficiency. Why this is obvious..? Is $R$ weakly compact? I think that $T$ is weakly compact operator, so $cl(T(ball R))$ is weakly compact, but it cannot deduce $R$ is weakly compact.

Comment: The closed unit ball $B$ of $R$ is weakly compact (because of the reflexivity) and hence $K=T(B)$ is also weakly compact because norm-continuous linear maps are weakly continuous.

Comment: @Jochen Yes, but I think that does not imply $X$ is Weakly Compact generated. $K$ is weakly compact, but it is not dense at $X$.

Comment: The linear span of $K$ is the range of $T$.

Comment: @jochen Thanks. I understanded.